# Rails 4/ turbolinks - only change one div - Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Does this only change the DIv 'thingtochange' ?

```
<body>
  <div id="main content">
    Sidebar, never changes after initial load.
  </div>

  <div id="thingtochange">
    You have <%= @comments.count %> comments.
  </div>


</body>

<script>
Turbolinks.visit(url, { change: 'thingtochange' });
</script>
```

am I using https://github.com/rails/turbolinks well?

I get an error  Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

What should i put instead of url : I just want this zone of the page to be reloaded.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What version of turbolinks are you using? IIRC partial replacement was 3+ but I may be mistaken.

Comment: it does not create any bug to say the truth but as a rookie I don't know to check if using this new 3+ Turbolinks.visit(url, { change: 'thingtochange' }); like I showed in my question makes only the div I target to change. or that it just reloads everything, removing the value of turbolinks...

Comment: to say the truth they speak about turbolink 3 but when I chekc in my gem list I have only turbolinks 2.5.3 where could I get turbolinks 3.0 ? (I am on master branch)